# Can a moderator share whatever it was that I said in this post's comments that has been deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

I'm assuming a mod can see deleted comments. At 15K I still cannot.

[Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json)

I managed to stumble across this question again today, and would like to know what it was that I had said that got that response.

Comment: After 10 years, I'm still a new contributor to Meta.

Comment: Note: *only* mods can see deleted comments.

Comment: *that got that response* Which response? Is there a comment from a moderator somewhere that we should be seeing?

Comment: @BSMP - The first one that I'm tagged in.

Comment: the new contributor on meta's [still in status review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314474/add-a-way-for-users-to-opt-out-of-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-their-own-p/314479#314479)

Comment: You won't ever see deleted comments. Only mods can see them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your comment there was the first one on the question and read in its entirety:

> Why would you want to?

It was deleted by Jeff Atwood on July 11, 2011 in a way that I apparently can't undelete it. I usually can undelete moderator-deleted comments, but I can't here. You're right, it kinda makes the rest of the comments a little hard to follow, but I can't seem to fix that.

Comment: You can't undelete moderator-deleted comments when the moderator who deleted them is no longer a moderator. It's probably a bug, arising from an incorrect conditional designed to prevent moderators from undeleting self-deleted comments.

Comment: Thanks, I dont need it undeleted. I've just come across that question a few times over the years and its bugged me to not know what it was that I said.

Comment: To fix it, just edit or delete the reply comments, or edit the useful information into the question...

Comment: or just elect Jeff again as a mod, so you can undelete the comment.

Comment: That's exactly what I guessed it was from the context, so I don't think it makes it that hard to follow the rest of the comments.

Comment: @BradLarson could you clarify if future "_what it was that I had said in a comment_" better fit for a moderator flag or a meta question?